Listen on this.$el.clientHeight in vue 3
In vue3, I need to stick my footer on the bottom whenever this.$el.clientHeight>window.innerHeight.
Since there is a big poster in my website that require loading, and may exist other things in the future, judge once during mounted() is not enough.
My current approach is really awkward: using timer.
In methods:
footerSticky() {
  if (this.$el.clientHeight < window.innerHeight) {
    this.$refs.footer.classList.add('sticky-footer');
    } else {
    this.$refs.footer.classList.remove('sticky-footer');
  }
}

In mounted:
setInterval(this.footerSticky, 500);

But I want to go over a listener/watcher approach. After battling with gpt and searching stack overflow for a while, I give up now and go here to ask the question.
Failed approach(es):

npm install @vueuse/core (which is version 10.9.0)
Then import by import { useResizeObserver } from '@vueuse/core';
And add:

mounted() {
  useResizeObserver(this.$el, () => {
    this.footerSticky();
  });
},

Failure: package raises many error after importing (not even adding the mount code) (@vueuse/core is said to be deprecated when install)

I suggest using the resize observer api to do action based on resizes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API
The recommended way to do that in Vue would be
https://vueuse.org/core/useResizeObserver/
In your case you can bind the value of the element sizes to two refs, then use computed to create a computed reference, then use effect or watch to trigger the document changes.
Beware of infinite loops though: adding/removing elements in the UI can cause a re-render with different sizes, which can end up reversing the change and triggering the re-render again...
Moreover, your particular case may be solvable through the more specific Intersection Observer api:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
which has a wrapper in
https://vueuse.org/core/useIntersectionObserver/

I will check out right away. Thank you!

I have checked this post before. But after importing @vueuse/core it will raise a tons of error which I have no ideas and also when installing it vue3 actually told me that it was deprecated as vue2->vue3.

what version of @vueuse/core are you using?

10.2.4, installed just now.

are you using the migration build of Vue3 (i.e., do you have @vue/compat installed)? Maybe that's the thing that is not compatible with vueuse

Sorry, 10.9.0, having used the wrong command. Also, @vue/cli has version 5.0.8

I added app.use(createCompatVue()); in main.js, problem persists.

@vueuse/core supports vue3 as of version 4. vue-cli is deprecated as well, as with all other vue2 tools. Is this a new project or did you migrate an existing vue2 project to vue3?

it is a new project.


  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "gpg": "^0.6.0",
    "openpgp": "^5.11.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },


Let us continue this discussion in chat.

See my self-answer, is it a good approach? (I know $refs will get defined in some tick so I am confident to poll here)

Update: I figured out the solution by polling on $refs and wait for it to be defined, and then set a watcher on it.
Inside async mounted:
while (this.$refs === undefined) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
}
// set watch on refs.el.clientHeight, when it changes, run footerSticky
this.$watch(() => this.$refs.el.clientHeight, 
  () => {
    this.footerSticky();
  }
);

Hope this solution is elegant and useful! If you have a better approach, let me know!
